# Vertical gap between column that shows only on iPad view

Tags: html, css

I get rid of a column gap using margin: 0; padding: 0; and float: left. All works fine until one day we found that this solution causes vertical gaps to shows up between columns on iPad device.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/pangpondpon/pen/NLrRad

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .col {
      width: 33.33333%;
      background-color: black;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      float: left;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

[image]

Does anyone has this problem before?. I would like to learn how you fix it or attempt to fix it. I've tried a few ways but they doesn't work, and now I'm not even sure if it can be solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - did you know that you can directly embed html, css and javascript into your question? Makes it much easier to answer questions like this.

Comment: I can confirm I can see the gaps on my computer (Chrome 68) - but only when the explicit mobile mode is on, and only in the code pen example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any gap between two div.

> It might be possible that another class's border is applying here, in this case apply `border:none` to `.col` class
>
> **Suggestion** : apply same background to its container

Check below code with any extra border:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row{
    background-color: #000;
}

.col {
  width: 33.33333%;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
<p>One more example : </p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" style="background-color:red"></div>
  <div class="col" style="background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="col" style="background-color:green"></div>
</div>
```

> It's an issue in iOS, for more info see:
>   http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3585/iphone-fail-the-trouble-with-table-borders-and-html-email

Comment: The gap only shows when open with iPad at the moment (so far that my customer found). My PC shows no gap too :/.

Please open that codepen and use Chrome dev tool to open iPad screen size, then you will see the gap. Not sure why that happens.

Comment: I have the very same issue. Setting `border` to `0` have solved my issue. Also, use FF dev tools. Chromes are weird (fails to load images, connection error to internet etc. even IE performs better)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll update the code and test it on iPad.

Comment: @PatompongSavaengsuk, code updated, check "Suggestion" in above answer.

Comment: Thanks for another suggestion, but the problem is now fixed by setting border to 0.